# How to delete rows which have names starting with [a-d]

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I wanted to delete rows where a name starts with either `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`. The code below does not seem to work. What does it do then?

```
DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName LIKE '[a-d]%';
```

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions in SQL.

Comment: Your code works for SQL Server and Access if you replace % with *.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `like`, then:

```
WHERE CustomerName like 'a%' OR
      CustomerName like 'b%' OR
      CustomerName like 'c%' OR
      CustomerName like 'd%'
```

With most collations, you can do:

```
WHERE CustomerName >= 'a' AND
      CustomerName < 'e'
```

Or, you can use `SUBSTRING()` or `LEFT()` (if your database supports it):

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(CustomerName, 1, 1) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'd'
```

Or regular expressions (although the syntax varies by databases and not all databases support them).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
DELETE FROM Customers WHERE UPPER(LEFT(CustomerName, 1)) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

Your query is [working on SQL Server / T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals). You can use the following to avoid issues with case sensitivity:

```
DELETE FROM Customers WHERE UPPER(CustomerName) LIKE '[A-D]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `like` doesn't support `regex` so, You can use this:

```
DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName >= 'A' and CustomerName < 'E'
```

It will delete all records that starts from `A, B, C or D`